# Shadowbox not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, drupal, shadowbox

I have a strange problem.
I have integrated shadowbox plugin into my drupal web and it works with Opera, Chrome and IE9, but it doesn't work with Firefox 14.

I've noticed that in Firefox `rel="shadowbox"` attribute is not added to the link of an image, so that should be the reason.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of Shadowbox is (usually) that you if add the `rel="shadowbox"` to a link, it will show the Shadowbox. Are you really sure that the attribute is not added in Firefox? Because if that is the cause, you're probably doing something extremely weird at the server side.

Are you trying to add the attribute using some client side code? Because then maybe that code gets execute after Shadowbox registers its event bindings. You might consider changing that code to really add shadowbox to the link, instead of just setting the attribute. Shadowbox provides a fairly decent API to do exactly that.